# Генерация текстов

Tags: javascript, python, sql

Добрый день всем!

Есть таблица, в которой хранятся некоторые данный по столбцам, и нужно сгенерировать текста по примеру: 
"Добрый день (имя из таблицы)! Вас не было (кол-во дней)" и тд.

Как лучше было бы выполнить эту задачу?

Comment: Ну, вероятно, получить данные запросом и отформатировать вывод...

Comment: Я бы сделал шаблон на Jinja2 и заполнил его данными из таблицы.